# KnockoutJs: How to delete multiple table row using check on knockoutJS?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Hi im trying to make a multiple row deletion on a table with KnockoutJs. I dont know why my code is not working when i try it to use on a table. I have tried this on ul and its working great.

below is my code. need help thanks in advance :(

HTML:

```
<table class="pure-table" id="tbl_ordered_products">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkAllProducts" /></th>
                <th>Product Code</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Discount Rate</th>
                <th>Stock Balance</th>
                <th>Total Discount</th>
                <th>Orig. Price</th>
                <th>Total</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: orderedProducts">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkAllProducts" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedOrderedProducts"/></td>
                <td data-bind="text: product_code"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: price"></td> 
                <td><input data-bind="value: quantity" /></td>
                <td><input data-bind="value: discount" /></td>
                <td data-bind="text: balance"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: total_discount"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: original_price"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: total_price"></td>
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
    </table>

<input type="button" value="Remove Selected" data-bind="click: deleteSelectedProducts" />
```

My JS:

```
function Product(id, product_number, name, price, quantity, discount, balance) {
var self = this;
self.id = ko.observable(id);
self.product_code = ko.observable(product_number);
self.name = ko.observable(name);
self.price = ko.observable(price.toFixed(2));
self.quantity = ko.observable(quantity);
self.discount = ko.observable(discount);
self.balance = ko.observable(balance);
}
function OrdersViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.customerCode = ko.observable();
self.full_name = ko.observable();
self.complete_address = ko.observable();
self.birthday = ko.observable();
self.email = ko.observable();
self.contact = ko.observable();

self.orderedProducts = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedOrderedProducts = ko.observableArray();

self.deleteSelectedProducts = function () {
    alert(self.selectedOrderedProducts.length);
    self.orderedProducts.removeAll(self.selectedOrderedProducts());
    self.selectedOrderedProducts.removeAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing a few things about how Knockout works here.

Compare this:

```
<table class="pure-table" id="tbl_ordered_products">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkAllProducts" data-bind="click: toggleAllProducts" />
            </th>
            <th><label for="chkAllProducts">Product Name</label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: orderedProducts">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected, attr: {id: htmlId}" />
            </td>
            <td><label data-bind="text: name, attr: {for: htmlId}"></label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Remove Selected" data-bind="click: deleteSelectedProducts" />
```

and

```
function Product(id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.htmlId = "product_" + id;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
}

function OrdersViewModel(products) {
    var self = this,
        productObjects = ko.utils.arrayMap(products, function (product) {
            return new Product(product.id, product.name);
        });

    self.orderedProducts = ko.observableArray(productObjects);

    self.selectedOrderedProducts = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.orderedProducts(), function (product) {
            return product.isSelected();
        });
    });
    self.toggleAllProducts = function (vm, e) {
        var checkboxState = e.target.checked;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.orderedProducts(), function (product) {
            product.isSelected(checkboxState);  
        });
        return true;
    };
    self.deleteSelectedProducts = function () {
        self.orderedProducts.removeAll(self.selectedOrderedProducts());
    };
}
```

- You don't have an `isSelected` observable on the products in your approach, but this is the key to have a working view model.
- On the other hand, you don't need a second array of selected products. "Selected products" is a sub-set of your products that can be calculated on the fly reliably. That means: Use a computed observable. `ko.utils.arrayFilter()` is very helpful here.
- Your checkboxes must not have a value binding. They "know" from context where they are, giving them a value binding breaks things. *(You will assemble data for subsequent Ajax requests directly from your view model anyway - not from your view. The checkbox value is irrelevant.)*
- You're missing a "toggle all" function, so I made one.
- Cosmetic change, but essential to the user experience: If you have checkboxes, you must have connected labels.
- Compare http://jsfiddle.net/SBzYj/

Answer (score 2):

Knockout `checked` binding down't work, when `value` is an `object`.
Use additional pbservable property `isChecked` in `Product` object

```
function Product(id, product_number, name, price, quantity, discount, balance) {
   var self = this;
   self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
   self.id = ko.observable(id);
   self.product_code = ko.observable(product_number);
   // ...
}
```

delete rows

```
self.deleteSelectedProducts = function () {
    var productToRemove = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.orderedProducts(), function(product){
       if (product.isChecked()) 
       {
           productToRemove.push(product)
       }
    })
    self.orderedProducts.removeAll(productToRemove)
}
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LUhfs/)

Comment: +1 that's the gist of it. Though I would use `arrayFilter` rather than  `arrayForEach` in the `deleteSelectedProducts()` method. That's more idiomatic *and* it would save half of the lines.